# How can I disable the function to add new update repositories?

Tags: eclipse, branding, update-site

In our environment, we are using our own update site (mirrors of the update repositories) to lower the traffic and to make the support easier, and we want that the users are using only this update site of us ... is it possible to disable the function to add new update sites?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your own update sites to an eclipse installation, you'll want to use P2 touchpoints to handle this, there is a [question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12840446/207764). This will make sure that your local mirrors are added to the users Eclipseinstallations.

As for disabling the ability to add update sites, afaik there is no way to do this in Eclipse without resorting to manipulating the code in Eclipse. If this is an important safety feature for you, you should look into products such as [Genuitecs Secure Delivery Center](http://www.genuitec.com/sdc/).